# JSX vs Component reference as value type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I have a requirement to render a specific component based on params. I have two solutions in mind.

Solution 1:

```
export const getForm = () => {
  const { name } = useParams();

  const ComponentMap = {
    account: <Account />,
    contact: <Contact />,
  };

  return ComponentMap[name];
};
```

Solution 2:

```
export const getForm = () => {
  const { name } = useParams();

  const ComponentMap = {
    account: Account,
    contact: Contact,
  };

  return <ComponentMap[name] />;
};
```

I am more inclined to solution 2 as it won't create JSX elements for all the map values.

What's the standard pattern in React world. Can someone help me in deciding an approach?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you would do is after you extract a property "name" from useParams, my suggestion would be that you pass it as a Props to the component.

Like this

```
export const getForm = () => {
  const { name } = useParams();

  const componentForm = {
    account: <Account name={name} />,
    contact: <Contact name={name} />,
  };

  return componentForm[name];
};
```

Then I would capture that in the componenet:

For example in Account.jsx

```
export const Account = ({name}) => {

getDetails(name)

}
```

At least that is what I would do using React and React Routers

Answer (score 0):

`Solution 1` is a common practice, `Solution 2` looks weird. Not sure about pros and cons, but `Solution 1` is how 99% of React devs do, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is for Solution #2.  This is a very powerful pattern as it allows you to pass through a standard set of props to any of your render components.  For example, perhaps we have other values in the params that we want to pass as props.  You could get props from other sources like redux, firebase, etc.

```
export const DynamicForm = () => {
    const { name, ...rest } = useParams();

    const ComponentMap = {
        account: Account,
        contact: Contact,
    };

    const Component = ComponentMap[name];

    return <Component {...rest} />;
};
```

With Typescript types:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

const Account = ({someProp}: {someProp: string}) => <div>{someProp}</div>

const Contact = ({otherProp}: {otherProp: string}) => <div>{otherProp}</div>

interface MyParamsType {
    name: string;
    someProp: string;
    otherProp: string;
}

export const DynamicForm = () => {
    const { name, ...rest } = useParams<MyParamsType>();

    // define the components' props as the type of `rest`
    const ComponentMap: Record<string, React.ComponentType<Omit<MyParamsType, 'name'>>> = {
        account: Account,
        contact: Contact,
    };

    const Component = ComponentMap[name];

    return <Component {...rest} />;
};
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mplgbm)